# Android Downgrade Issue

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, version-control, android-manifest

I am using Unity to build and create my app. I already have my app in the Play store with this version number:

**4220 (4.2.2)**

I also have the application installed on my android device.

Now, I have created a new version of my app and added this into my manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx" 
    android:installLocation="preferExternal" 
    android:versionCode="5000" 
    android:versionName="5.0.0">
```

(x's is off course my app ID)

Now, when building from Unity I get this error:

**Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]**

Now, I have searched the net for solutions to this, and can't see what I am doing wrong here?!?!?

Please help, and any help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity overwrites the values of your custom **AndroidManifest.xml** with the several configurations in the **Player Settings**.

So check your values under Edit > Project Settings > Player > Android > Other Settings > Identification > **Version** and **Bundle Version Code**.

You can inspect the merged AndroidManifest.xml of the APK with a tool like [ClassyShark](https://github.com/google/android-classyshark)

Comment: Perfect... Missed the bundle version... Was set to 1 :-/